# Sharing internet to Private WAN routing

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, vlan, wide-area-network

I'm trying to help out with sharing internet over a private WAN installed between two sites, unfortunately the routers are controlled by a company that won't respond to support requests, but they have provided some very basic documentation.

**HEAD OFFICE:**
 PROVIDER EQUIPMENT (Fibre Optic, provider managed Juniper SRX100)

-Internet comes in via Juniper SRX100 (provider equipment) 
Port 6 Juniper: Public IP Internet (IP Block, no NAT) 
Port 7 Juniper: Private WAN, SUBNET IP segment 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.6 Mask: 255.255.255.248 Gateway: 192.168.1.1 (Details as provided)

Head office customer Equipment:
 -Meraki MX60 router, currently serving internet through port 6 juniper (Public IP) to local office.

**FIELD OFFICE:** 
 PROVIDER EQUIPMENT: (Satellite connection, provider managed Juniper SRX100)
 -No Public internet connection Juniper SRX100 (Provider equipment) IP Segment: 192.168.2.2 - 192.168.2.6  Mask: 255.255.255.248 Gateway: 192.168.2.1

Field office customer equipment (Not configured on in use): 
 -Draytek Vigor2830n wifi router (Has ethernet WAN port) , As you can see, the field office does not have public internet, only a private WAN over a small subnet.

Question?

I'm looking for some help to configure the correct routing rules/setup for the Meraki and Draytek to share the head office internet over the private WAN. I assume the routing rules are in place on the Junipers as they have provided these details.

I Think I need to do something along the lines of this?:

Head office:

1. Connect Port 7 of Juniper head office to Meraki MX60 as a new VLAN 20
2. Set subnet of VLAN 20 as 192.168.1.0/29 (Set VLAN 20 Meraki Appliance IP 192.168.1.2)

Field Office:
 Setup Draytek Vigor2830n as Internet: WAN IP 192.168.2.2 mask 255.255.25.248 gateway 192.168.2.1, DNS: 192.168.2.1

-Enable DHCP & NAT on Draytek (NAT to share internet of 192.168.2.2, configure as normal modem, e.g. NAT 172.30.0.0 subnet)

**Now this is where I'm confused, how do I tell the Draytek to use the Meraki at 192.168.1.2 for the default gateway for the internet? its on a different subnet so I can't set the default gateway in the draytek WAN as 192.168.1.2? so what options do I have? is it possible without modifying the Junipers? establish a VPN to 192.168.1.x ? or set up static routes on the draytec( if so what??)**

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm all cross eye'd reading your description, but I think what you are asking is "how do i route traffic from 192.168.2.x out to the internet via 192.168.1.1.  Assuming there aren't any road blocks (ie, provider installed firewall rules etc), you should be able to have the default route on 192.168.2.x point to 192.168.2.1, in turn pointing any traffic on that to the 192.168.1.x subnet.  The problem is, it sounds like you might be missing a default route on the field office side. In which case, they might have added a static router for 192.168.1.x, but not a default route.  (Just thinking out loud here).  But my suspicion is that you are simply missing a default route that points to the VPN connection and back to the head office.

I don't think your VLAN option will work unless your VPN is setup to encapsulate that traffic over the link.  That sounds like black voodoo dark side magic.  I'd keep it simple and fix your routing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes my question is basically how do i route traffic from 192.168.2.x (field office) out to the internet via 192.168.1.1 (gateway in head office) ... From the field office if I setup a computer with IP 192.168.2.2 mask 255.255.255.248 gateway 192.168.2.1 then I can PING 192.168.1.1 (the Meraki) but no internet 

but how to route all internet traffic via 192.168.1.1 ? because if I set default gateway to 192.168.1.1 its on a different subnet to 192.168.2.x

Comment: The VPN connection would need to know to route traffic out the VPN tunnel for traffic other than 192.168.1.x.  Odds are, you'll probably need to adjust your VPN local and remote networks to allow the system to do this.  If the vendor refuses to help, you might be stuck.  One workaround, might be to install a proxy server at the main office and use that for the remote office.  Once you do that, so long as the remote office can see the main office's proxy server, it can hand off the traffic to the web at the main office instead. (Icky, but doable).

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure your right on the nail with the default route missing... I'm trying again to get support to see if they can fix it up, if not as an alternative to proxy I was thinking it might be possible to VPN into the head office (assuming it passes the protocol) for internet, with the Draytek as a client of the Meraki.., thanks for your help i'll see how I go

Comment: VPNing into the main office might work too if you set the flag to send all traffic via the VPN gateway instead of the local gateway.  I know the VPN client in Windows allow this.  I can't speak for your hardware as I am not familiar with them, but it stands to reason a similar option might be available.

Answer (score 0):

I finally had a response from the provider, they said quote: "The system is provided as two separate services, in this case it is recommended you use a proxy server to route the private WAN to the internet connection" ... not very professional service :( but I'll have to go about using a workaround (Proxy/VPN)

Comment: That is a doable workaround and simple enough to implement..